# Eclipse Git - Compare different branch previous version

Tags: eclipse, git

In git using eclipse i want to current commit of one Branch to the previous version different Branch.

Using "Compare With" option in eclipse, i was able to compare with different branch or with same branch previous versions. But i want to compare with different branch's previous version.

For e.g Branch A has 3 commits aa ab and ac.
Branch B has 3 commits ba bb and bc.

I want to compare branch B's bc commit (latest) with Branch A's aa commit (not with command line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the eGit plugin [supports what you want to do](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Comparing_Content):

**Comparing Two Commits**

- Select a resource in the Package Explorer
- click Team > Show in History or Compare With > History... (the latter for files only)
- in the commit graph select two commits
- right-click Compare with each other
- this will open a compare dialog showing the changes between the two selected commi
- you can also open a Git Tree Compare view by right-clicking Compare with each other in Tree

The trick will be in finding the commit graph view so that you can manually choose the `bc` and `aa` commits from your two branches.

Comment: Thanks Tim. It works :). I can't up vote you though as I dont have 15 points Yet

Answer (score 0):

- Project file - Right Click -> Team -> Show in history
- ctrl+click the two versions you would like to compare
- Right Click -> Compare with each other

This will bring up the two versions you would like to compare